# Using AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have used the [Authorize] attribute in an ASP.NET Web API method

```
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
```

From the application I can access this method without a problem as my user is already authenticated. However, is there any way that I can specify the username, password to this method when calling so that I can implement a REST API? This is when calling from a standalone application or the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't entirely understand your question but `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` checks against `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to see if the user is authorized or not.

You can specifically give user permissions if you want as below:

```
[Authorize(Users = "User1")]
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
```

But the Authentication process is entirely up to you. I would recommend authenticating the user through a message handler and then populating the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` there. Then, use the `AuthorizeAttribute` as you see fit for your application.

Comment: I actually implemented a custom authorization based on the method header, So any 3rd party user can also be authenticated.